# Runtime safety for Arrays vs Collections in Java

Tags: java, arrays, generics, arraylist, collections

Collections do not provide runtime safety, they only provide compile time safety.
But I read that arrays provide runtime as well as compile time safety.

Since Lists are built on top of an array, they too can provide runtime safety. But why is this not provided?

If we take a look at sourcecode of ArrayList the array is declared as follows:
http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayList.java.html

```
private transient Object[] elementData;
```

could it not be changed to

```
private transient T[] elementData;
```

Comment: There's no functional difference between the two.  However, if you want runtime safety, check out Java's [checked collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#checkedList%28java.util.List,%20java.lang.Class%29)

Comment: When you declare an array as `MyClass[]` then it's restricted at runtime to only contain MyClass objects.  When you declare an `ArrayList<MyClass>` it can, at runtime, contain any sort of object.  In this sense the array is "safer".  The reason Lists do not provide runtime safety is that the array within is always an `Object[]`, regardless of the generic class you specify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring it `T[]` doesn't make it checked at runtime, cause at runtime the T parameter is erased and reduced to the lowest bound, which is Object, so it will de facto be `Object[]` anyway.

This is because Java implements generics with erasure, so the same .class file is used for `ArrayList<String>` as well as for `ArrayList<Integer>`. This means that, after compile time, they are the same in the JVM memory.

To have "real" different arrays, that is `String[]` in one and `Integer[]` in the other which would give you runtime checks, you would need two different .class, or at least a massive use of reflection that would slow down things quite a bit.

Comment: There's actually ways of implementing a type-safe array without "massive amounts of reflection", but Java collection just weren't designed for it.  It's not a big deal in practice -- a checked collection works well enough.

Comment: Sure they work, my answer was mainly to make him understand the motivation why it is not provided, which IIUC is what he asked.

Comment: Thanks for explaining me the internals Simone.